# nginx - 403 returned when I specified the location to my folder in Mac

Tags: nginx

I have `nginx` configuration like this:

```
location /myweb/ {
   #alias html/myweb/app/;
   alias /Users/admin/Documents/Projects/myweb/app/;
   index index.html;
}
```

When I place my project under my local folder(/Users/admin/Documents/Projects/myweb), 403 is returned when I visit with `http://localhost/myweb`, but if I place it into the `html` folder under `nginx` home folder, it works.

I even tried `chmod -R 777 xxx`, and start `nginx` with `sudo`. But it still returns 403.

Did I miss any settings for `nginx`?

Comment: This location should have access to ROOT user /Users/admin/Documents/Projects/myweb/app/, you should do `sudo chown root:root -R XXX`

Comment: This is what I got:`chown: root: illegal group name`. What's the default group?

Comment: You don't need chown. But all the folders to you app must have executable bit for "others". My bet, that `/Users/admin/` has not

Comment: what is the os you are running nginx on ? & please provide output of  "ls -al /" & "ls -la /Users/admin/Documents/Projects/myweb/app/"

Comment: @AlexeyTen @Pratik Shah All files have the permission like this: `rwxrwxrwx`.

Answer (score 0):

The `location /myweb/` does not match the URI `/myweb`. It is the fact that there is a directory called `myweb` under `html` that makes it work at the alternative root. But the simple solution is to fix the `location` and `alias` to match that URI, rather than just its descendants.

```
location /myweb {
    alias /Users/admin/Documents/Projects/myweb/app;
    index index.html;
}
```

Remove the trailing `/` from **both** the `location` and `alias` directives.

Comment: Thanks for your help and explanation, but it didn't work for my case.